# Keypress function didn't work when user types Burmese language

Tags: angular, typescript

HTML

```
<input [title]="walletRegistrationModel.Customer.FirstName" [disabled]="pageName == 'view'"
                    type="text" name="firstName" #firstName="ngModel" placeholder="First Name"
                    [(ngModel)]="walletRegistrationModel.Customer.FirstName" class="form-control" maxlength="100"
                    required (keypress)="common.onlyAlphanumericAndThaiAndSpecial($event,true)"
                    (paste)="common.validateAlphanumericAndThaiAndSpecial($event,true)" />
```

Component.ts

```
public onlyAlphanumericAndThaiAndSpecial(event: any, isSpaceAllowed?: boolean) {
    console.log(1);
    let pattern = isSpaceAllowed ? new RegExp('^([\u0E00-\u0E7Fa-zA-Z0-9@!#\$\^%&*()+=\\-\_\[\\]\\\\\';,\.\/\{\}\|\":<>\? ])*$') : new RegExp('^([\u0E00-\u0E7Fa-zA-Z0-9@!#\$\^%&*()+=\\-\_\[\\]\\\\\';,\.\/\{\}\|\":<>\?])*$');
    console.log('Enter');
    if (event) {
        console.log(pattern.test(event.key));
        return pattern.test(event.key);
    }
    return false;
}
```

I have a textbox and when user types something in the textbox, it will fire "keypress" event which will call this "onlyAlphanumericAndThaiAndSpecial" function to check with the regex pattern. The problem is when I type someting in Burmese language, the system doesn't call this "onlyAlphanumericAndThaiAndSpecial" function. It's like the keypress function didn't fire this "onlyAlphanumericAndThaiAndSpecial" function. Do you guys have any idea what cause this?

Comment: I am able to filter only Thai, English and certain special characters while Burmese is filtered out. Can you give us an example that is not working?

Comment: @krismath You mean my code? or just an example of Burmese word, if that what you ask then it was any word that is Burmese. PS. I already posted the full code.

Comment: Your regex string is ``^([฀-๿a-zA-Z0-9@!#$^%&*()+=\-_[\]\\';,./{}|":<>? ])*$``. Are you sure it should match Burmese words? See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/b5Eus5/1)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Actually, it shouldn't. I tried to debug and found that the keypress function on HTML page didn't call "onlyAlphanumericAndThaiAndSpecial" function when I typed word in Burmese language. Any idea what cause this?